# Swift 4 using URLSession with non-secure URL

Tags: swift, xcode, urlsession

I'm trying to send data to a WebAPI service that uses HTTP and not HTTPS, however I get the following error:

*"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"*

Here is my code:

```
func logSample(emailSKU:String) -> String {
    //let myAPI = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=25/json"
    let myAPI = "http://<myURlHere>/api/xxx"
    let url = URL(string: myAPI)
    let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url)!) { (data, response, error) in   <====== Breaks on this line

    print("Response was:")
    print(response)
 }
    session.resume()
    return "return something here"
}
```

The API service works just fine from other applications.
If I use the iTunes url above, then everything works fine, so the only difference is the HTTP ver HTTPS.

I have added 'Allow Arbitrary Loads' declaration to the plist, any ideas?

Comment: This isn't because of HTTP/HTTPS, this is because your `url` variable is nil.

Comment: Please show the full url that fails. From the Apple docs: "[URL] Returns nil if a URL cannot be formed with the string (for example, if the string contains characters that are illegal in a URL, or is an empty string)."

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show the full url for security reasons but this is what it returns: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">200</string>

Comment: The url looks like this: http://example.com/api/Scans?emailSKU=fred@example.com|123456

Comment: Is '|' an allowed url character?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) and it is the "|" character that isn't allowed and that you need to encode.

Comment: ah, I see, I'll get with the developer of that API and see if it can be changed

Answer (score 0):

To supplement @Joakims answer:

The URL given is invalid because of the use of the | character and needs to be encoded. You can do this in the following way:

```
let urlString = "http://example.com/api/Scans?emailSKU=fred@example.com|123456"
if let encodedURLString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {

    let url = URL(string: encodedURLString)
    print(url)
}
```

Which outputs:

> Optional(http://example.com/api/Scans?emailSKU=fred@example.com%7C123456)

So `|` needs to be encoded, which replaces it with `%7C`